# How to put the sum of two functions in an array in javascript-vuejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, function, vue.js

Hello there my problem is that I want to add two functions, and the sum I want to put it in another array; do I need the revenue as an array or if I let it as a function is fine? I thought also that it would be better to assign the numa in function as an array because of that button.
Also, when i trie to put it like `this.functionA+this.functionB` the result is ,.
Basically, the whole idea is that i need to calculate a revenue for each month so I added a button and made arrays to parse in the results and then project them.
The code of  is the following:

```
export default{
name: 'Home',
data(){
    return{
        FormData: {
            revenue:[
                {
                    lollipops:[
                        {
                            lolliSold:0,
                            pricePerLolli:0,
                        }
                    ],
                    chocolate:[
                        {
                            numchocoSold:0,
                            pricePerChoco:0,
                        }
                    ],
                    numa:0,
                    oprod:0
                }
            ] }}
computed: {
   lolliesSale(){
        let SaleArray=[];
        this.FormData.revenue.forEach((ItemL, indexL)=>{
            SaleArray[indexL]=ItemL.lollipops[0].lolliSold+ItemL.lollipops[0].pricePerLolli;
        });
        return SaleArray;
    },
    chocolateSale(){
        let choSaleArray=[];
        this.FormData.revenue.forEach((ItemC, indexC)=>{
            choSaleArray[indexC]=ItemC.chocolate[0].numchocoSold*ItemC.chocolate[0].pricePerChoco;
        });
        return choSaleArray;
    },
    numaSupport(){
        let numaSuppArray=[];
        this.FormData.revenue.forEach((ItemN, indexN)=>{
            numaSuppArray[indexN]=ItemN.numa;
        });
        return numaSuppArray;
    },
    revenue(){
    //return this.<anyfunction>; <- this is ok!!!!
    }
```

[image: img of what i want with calculations]

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand exactly what you are trying to achieve, can you please provide expected output by given input. Or better, create a snippet.

Comment: What exactly are `numa` and `oprod`?

Comment: @CristianS. please check the image

Comment: @DigitalDrifter oprod goes for Other Sweet and numa for Other Income

Comment: @Antwnina your images tells me that what you are trying to achieve is the revenue of the month depending on how many items were sold and their price. But why are u parsing arrays? If you create a working snippet it would be easier to help you to rewrite a better solution.

Comment: @CristianS. because with the button those all fields are added dynamically and in the future, I want to create a "delete Month" to delete column

**lolliesSale =**  lolliSold *pricePerLolli 
**chocolateSale =**  numchocoSold * pricePerChoco 
**revenue =**   lolliesSale + chocolateSale + numaSupport

Comment: @CristianS. i don't know if with calculations  it's more understandable

Comment: @CristianS.  can you vote my question and answer if you liked it? thanks

Comment: @DigitalDrifter can you vote my question and answer if you liked it? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the numa computed function to make an array it doesn't need since for each Year I have only one numa(=other Income)
so, in revenue I reference to the previous functions in the corresponding index, the index shows the position of the array.

```
export default{
name: 'Home',
data(){
    return{
        FormData: {
            revenue:[
                {
                    lollipops:[
                        {
                            lolliSold:0,
                            pricePerLolli:0,
                        }
                    ],
                    chocolate:[
                        {
                            numchocoSold:0,
                            pricePerChoco:0,
                        }
                    ],
                    numa:0,
                    oprod:0
                }
            ] }}
computed: {
   lolliesSale(){
        let SaleArray=[];
        this.FormData.revenue.forEach((ItemL, indexL)=>{
            SaleArray[indexL]=ItemL.lollipops[0].lolliSold+ItemL.lollipops[0].pricePerLolli;
        });
        return SaleArray;
    },
    chocolateSale(){
        let choSaleArray=[];
        this.FormData.revenue.forEach((ItemC, indexC)=>{
            choSaleArray[indexC]=ItemC.chocolate[0].numchocoSold*ItemC.chocolate[0].pricePerChoco;
        });
        return choSaleArray;
    },
revenue(){
            let revenueArray=[];
            this.FormData.revenue.forEach((rItem, indexR)=>{
                revenueArray.push(this.lolliesSale[indexR] + this.chocolateSale[indexR] + this.FormData.revenue[indexR].numa);
           });
           return revenueArray;
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

ok, so create an array monthlyRevenues: [],
at the end of each month, push totalRevenue into the array and set totalRevenue to zero.  you can do the same with any items you have in the store.  then use a v-for each item in monthlyRevenues and display them on the page {{item}}

Comment: `computed: {
revenue(){
            let revenueArray=[];
            this.FormData.revenue.forEach((rItem, indexR)=>{
                revenueArray.push(rItem. lolliesSale);
//what exaclty to push
//how to declare totalRevenue
           });
           return revenueArray;
        }
}`

Comment: html:
`<v-card>
<v-container fluid grid-list-sm>
<v-layout row wrap>
<v-flex xs3 v-for="(revenueItem, indexRev) in FormData.revenue"
 :key="indexRev">
<v-text-field
      :label="'Revenue of Month '+indexRev+ ': '"
       disabled
       :value="revenue"> </v-text-field>
</v-flex> 
</v-layout>
</v-container>  
</v-card>`

Comment: I'm APOLOGIZING about the indentation but here in comments i couldn't so it (tried ``)

Comment: can you vote my question and answer if you liked it? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve here.

It seems like you want to keep track of total revenue, and how much of each item is sold.  I dont understand why you have arrays in your data.  all you need is a single variable for each of the things you are tracking.

`Data() {
return {
chocPrice: 5,
lolliPrice: 5,
otherPrice: 1,
totalRevenue: 0,
lolliSold: 0,
chocSold: 0,`

create a button that will trigger a method. 
`<button v-on:click="buyChocolate">Buy Chocolate</button>`

whenever a chocolate/lollipop is sold you can trigger a method that will increment your totalRevenue by the price of that item as well as increment the number of chocolate/lollipop sold

`chocSold++, totalRevenue = totalRevenue+chocPrice`.

then you can render those items on the page with something like {{totalRevenue}}

Comment: because i want to see all the revenues of each month in the same page like the picture

Comment: can you vote my question and answer if you liked it? thanks